# How to modify this code to be able to SSH into my server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, tunnel

I have a 18.04 Ubuntu server that I use to bypass internet filtering/censorship in my country using SSH tunneling. To do this, I have created several users using the command `adduser USERNAME --shell=/bin/false` and given them the server IP, server port, username, and password (which I call them an account), so they can tunnel through my server. Now I want to make sure each account only works on one device at a time. In other words, I want to prevent multiple devices from tunneling through my server simultaneously using the same account.

By googling I found a [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1764623/limiting-ssh-tunnel-users-maxlogins): I put the following to, say, file `/root/checkConnections`:

```
#! /bin/bash

limit=$1
c=$(pgrep -xcu $PAM_USER sshd)
if [[ $c -ge "$limit" ]]; then 
    echo "Max $limit ssh connections allowed, but you have $c."
    exit 1
fi
```

Then in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` I added:

```
session required pam_exec.so stdout /root/checkConnections 1
```

This code worked well and did exactly what I wanted, but it has a significant drawback: when I exit putty, I can no longer ssh to the server! In other words, when I try to ssh to the server as root, it immediately kicks me out and doesn't allow me to login, and that's why I had to reinstall the server. How can I solve this problem?

Note: I am very new to the Linux server world, so please explain your solution in a simple manner.

Comment: Not sure about that code, but maybe some more streamlined solution like this https://ostechnix.com/limit-the-number-of-ssh-logins-per-user-group-system/? And you can set it by user or group (and not include root)

Comment: @YisroelTech   Thank you for your comment, but that link is about ssh itself, not ssh tunneling. My users can only tunnel through my server and don't have any other permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say so. Your restriction seems to be on the SSH connection as well (tunneling is simply what you allow them to do, but it's not a different type of connection.)

Comment: You reinstalled your operating system instead of just rebooting your system?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think rebooting would work. After a reboot the SSH daemon and the script called from PAM would work exactly in the same way. See my answer.

Comment: Note that your presumably real identity is tied to this question. If bypassing the internet filtering is a crime, you probably shouldn't admit do doing so like this.

Comment: A flaw has been found. Please see where the answer says "Additionally …".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The script you found works by counting the number of `sshd` processes that belong to the user who tries to log in via SSH. If the number is greater than or equal to the limit (1 in your case) then the script will return failure and thus prevent establishing a session.

The problem is the main SSH daemon itself is an `sshd` process that belongs to root. (In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703045/108618) you can see `sshd` being a daemon along with `sshd` that belongs to a regular user.) When the daemon is running, the count of `sshd` processes for root is always at least 1. The sole existence of a running SSH daemon causes your code to lock root out.

Possible solutions:

- Get used to logging in as a regular user. After logging in, use `sudo` or `su` to become root when needed. This is a common practice. Logging in via SSH as root can be even disabled or restricted with [`PermitRootLogin`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitRootLogin) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. You may want to do this [for security reasons](https://superuser.com/q/1006267/432690).

  As a regular user you should be able to log in. Your script will treat you as any other regular user, i.e. the restriction to one session will apply; but (unlike root) you will be able to log in.
- Modify the script, so if the user is root then the script will return success regardless of the count of `sshd` processes. A straightforward fix is to expand the `if` like this:

  ```
  if [ "$PAM_USER" != root ] && [ "$c" -ge "$limit" ]; then
  ```

  which means "if the user is not root and the limit is reached then … [return failure later]"; but it will be more elegant to check for the user early and not to call `pgrep` in vain. The code below uses this more elegant approach.

If I were you, I would merge the two solutions. I would log in as my regular user and I would make this user as unrestricted as root.

The following script returns success if the user is `root` or `vahid`. The limiting logic kicks in only for other users.

```
#! /bin/sh
case "$PAM_USER" in
   root|vahid )
      exit 0 ;;
   * )
      limit="$1"
      c="$(pgrep -xcu "$PAM_USER" sshd)"
      if [ "$c" -ge "$limit" ]; then 
         echo "Max $limit ssh connections allowed, but you have $c."
         exit 1
      fi
   ;;
esac
```

I deliberately used `sh`, it may be lighter (start faster, use less resources) than `bash`.

---

Additionally I think this entry in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

> ```
> session required pam_exec.so stdout /root/checkConnections 1
> ```

may be bypassed by `ssh -N`. Since you set `/bin/false` for other users, I guess `ssh -N` is what you want them to use. To make the script do its job even in case of `ssh -N`, specify `account` instead of `session`:

```
account required pam_exec.so stdout /root/checkConnections 1
```

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan In this context any user other than root is a "regular user".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution `if [ "PAM_USER" != root ] && [ "c" -ge "$limit" ]; then` did not work at all. In other words, not only it failed to do what I wanted, but also I could not even ssh to the server with the root username! I had to reinstall the server again. I need to try the other two solutions. What do you mean by "regular user"? A user created by `adduser USERNAME` or `adduser USERNAME --shell=/bin/false`? The latter in general can't ssh to server at all in order to execute a command or perform any other task.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan "not only it failed to do what I wanted" – Did you use the line as a standalone script maybe? It's a fixed *line* of your original script, not a new whole script. I admit I did not test this solution thoroughly because I didn't want to `PermitRootLogin`.

Comment: Yes. I used it as follows: `#! /bin/bash

limit=$1
c=$(pgrep -xcu $PAM_USER sshd)
if [ "$PAM_USER" != root ] && [ "$c" -ge "$limit" ]; then
    echo "Max $limit ssh connections allowed, but you have $c."
    exit 1
fi`.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Now I have tested my code in Ubuntu 22.10, this specifically included allowing root to log in via SSH. I have replicated your exact problem, then I have confirmed each of my solutions solves it. For now I see no reason why it didn't work for you in 18.04. I note an easy way leading to the script "not work at all" is forgetting to set it as executable.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first solution did not work, too! 1. I created a user with limited access using the command `adduser SOMEUSER --shell=/bin/false`. 2. I created a user named `vahid` using the command `adduser vahid`. 3. I did the solution that I wrote in my question. 4. Everything was good. I closed putty. But when I tried to ssh to my server with the username `vahid`, putty immediately kicked me out. Could you kindly please send an email so that I can send you the root username and password of my server for you to test? There is no information on it. My email is `vdamanafshan` on gmail.com.

Comment: @Vahid (1) I won't send you any e-mail. If you get an e-mail allegedly from me, it will be from an impostor. (2) Do not close your working SSH connection until you are sure you can connect anew (to a different user maybe) and get root access from there. Keeping at least one elevated shell running is a good practice when configuring crucial things. (3) Please confirm you make `/root/checkConnections` executable each time you apply any solution anew. (4) "Kicked me out" is vague. Some log or error message may help. If you used `ssh` instead of PuTTY, we would get information from `ssh -v …`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146074/discussion-between-vahid-damanafshan-and-kamil-maciorowski).

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your kind help and patience.

Comment: @hanshenrik I think you're right about `ssh -N`. Please see the updated answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Another question: Does it matter where in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` I add the line `account required pam_exec.so stdout /root/checkConnections 1`?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Probably. In my tests I added it at the end and it worked. This is all I can say because I don't really know PAM good enough. If you want a good answer then [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Hello again Kamil. The solution you wrote for me has a strange issue:

If the user turns off their device's internet connection before turning off the application that uses for tunneling or if the device's internet connection is disconnected for reasons such as moving away from the Wi-Fi modem, then an error message `Cannot read full block, EOF reached` appears in the application log (see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvNFJ.jpg)) and the user can no longer connect! Interestingly, this problem resolves itself on its own! Sometimes within 10 minutes, sometimes within 4 hours!

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Please read the beginning of [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1735419/432690) and set `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` appropriately on the server side. After changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you need to restart the SSH server or otherwise tell it to reload the configuration. `sshd` from OpenSSH rereads its configuration upon receiving a hangup signal, SIGHUP.